# Conventional current and electron flow in Arduino

Tags: arduino, current, electron

On an Arduino there are some pins named GND, some are 5 V, and so on. If electrons flow from the negative to the positive terminal, then does this mean that they are flowing from GND to one of the other pins in the circuit?

It does not make sense to me that, considering electron flow, why, for example, if the load is an LED and its positive leg is connected to a non-GND pin (like 5 V) and the negative leg is connected to the GND pin, then why does the positive pin say 5 V if electrons are flowing from the ground?

I'm a bit confused and the question may not sound clear, but if any of you have experienced the same confusion early on, maybe you can help out?

Comment: Conventional and "real" flows are exactly the oposite. If you "mix" the two, they will contradict each other. When you read GND and 5V, you are reading conventional flow, but when you think of the electron leaving GND, you are thinking about the "real" flow. TL/DR is, when dealing with stuff on a component level, dont ever think about the "real" flow, just use the conventional notations/namings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On an Arduino there are some pins named GND, some are 5 V, and so on. If electrons flow from the negative to the positive terminal, then does this mean that they are flowing from GND to one of the other pins in the circuit?

Yes, it does.

> It does not make sense to me that, considering electron flow, why, for example, if the load is an LED and its positive leg is connected to a non-GND pin (like 5 V) and the negative leg is connected to the GND pin, then why does the positive pin say 5 V if electrons are flowing from the ground?

Because the convention (and it is a convention) for what is positive, and what sign charge has, was established, and working quite happily, well before we had any notion of electrons. Most engineers, physicists, etc, think in terms of conventional current, that flows from positive to negative, and do their work, and their intuition, just fine using that convention.

> I'm a bit confused and the question may not sound clear, but if any of you have experienced the same confusion early on, maybe you can help out?

It is confusing to take two opposite conventions (conventional, and how electrons are moving), and trying to work in both at the same time.

I heard an apocryphal story of a missile that for some reason had to be stored upside-down. There was a notice on the side. 'This missile must be stored upside-down. To avoid confusion, the top has been labelled bottom, and the bottom labelled top'.

To avoid your confusion, just work in conventional current. All engineers and physicists use it, simulators use it, all schematics are labelled using it, all meters and power supplies are labelled using it. Circuits work just fine when you design them using it. Thevnin, KCL, Ohm's Law, all work fine using it.

Now you have learnt about them, forget about electrons. They will almost never be useful to you. If you do plasma physics, or solid state physics, and a few other specialised disciplines, then you'll need to use them. But you'll probably need them at the quantum mechanics level, not the billiard ball particle level, which is a whole different game. If you look up the [Drude Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model), you'll see how enticing, and lacking in predictive power, they are.

I would argue that the [hydraulic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy), which is **obviously** nothing to do with electrical reality, is probably more **useful**, a better introduction to electricity, than the 'electrons pinging about' model. For one, it's obviously wrong, so it's easy to drop it and move on when you need to. For two, potential (voltage) is in there quite naturally and intuitively, which the electron model struggles with.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really cleared out a lot of confusion I had.

Answer (score 0):

Positive charges (if there are any) naturally "fall" towards places of lower potential, losing potential energy as they do so, in the same way objects with mass fall downwards. That energy is conserved, though, and converted to other forms, such as light, or heat, or motion. This conversion is called "doing work".

Electrons, being negatively charged, have the most potential energy at places with low potential (voltage), and they naturally "fall" towards a more positive point. If there existed objects with negative mass, they'd fall upwards too. In "falling", they also lose potential energy, energy which is converted to other forms.

This is because nothing ever moves to a position of higher potential energy for the same reason things don't float upwards in gravity, *unless* they are pushed there, by giving them energy somehow.

As you can see, it doesn't matter what sign the charge has, it always flows to a place of lower potential energy (unless it's pushed in the other direction, which is what happens when you charge a battery), and the energy it loses does some kind of work.

Stop thinking about electrons, it's confusing because they seem to fall "upwards". Think only in terms of positive charges flowing towards the lower potential, unless given energy somehow to flow in the other direction. The maths is exactly the same in all cases, regardless of the charge polarity. A negative charge moving one way is exactly equivalent to a positive charge in the same medium going the other way.